# How to get and modify data in a grid cell CSS

Tags: javascript, css, grid, frontend

I have 8 rows and 8 columns in the grid layout. Suppose I want to modify data on 5th row and 3rd column at runtime on click of a button. How can I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Give each grid an id and use it in JS to modify it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+change+cell+content+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: please add your code and what you tried so far

Comment: I have tried nothing because I cannot figure it out. How to I am going to have 1000 by 1000 grid giving each one id is not possible.